# Confusing language on arduino docs about powering via 3V3/5V pins

Tags: power

I'm reading about [powering alternatives for the arduino board](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/electronics/power-pins), and I have run across two confusing sentences in Section 5, powering via 3V3/5V pin. First, it says:

> 3V3 and 5V pins **can also be used as power inputs if no regulated power supply is connected** through the other power inputs (USB port, barrel jack connector or VIN pin).

But then right afterwards, it says:

> Although 3V3 and 5V pins can be used as power inputs, it is **not recommended if no power supply is connected** through the USB port, the barrel jack connector, or the VIN pin.

(emphasis mine)

Which is correct? When powering via the 3V3 or 5V pin, should I have a different power supply connected elsewhere, or not?

Comment: they are both correct ... one says `you can do this` ... the second one says `but it is not recommended that you do this` ... similar to  `you can run across the street` ... `but it is not recommended that you run across the street` .... they are basically saying `don't use the arduino as a power supply if you can avoid it`

Comment: The issue appears to be backfeeding the voltage regulator which is connected to the 3.3v or 5v pins. Some voltage regulators don't like it (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110314/how-can-i-tell-if-my-power-supply-regulator-will-accept-backfed-current).